# Endless CountdownTimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Here I have this CountDownTimer which I want to start and restart on an endless loop and I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
 prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

   xtime = System.currentTimeMillis()-prefs.getLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis());      

   timer=24000-(xtime+prefs.getLong("time2",0)); 

   final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   editor.putLong("time2",xtime+prefs.getLong("time2",0));  

   editor.commit(); 

   new CountDownTimer(timer, 1000) { 

     public void onTick(long elapsed) {

        long timer2=elapsed;
        hours = timer2 / hours_in_millies;
        timer2 %= hours_in_millies;
        minutes = timer2 / minutes_in_millies;
        timer2 %= minutes_in_millies;
        Log.v(TAG, "seconds" + seconds);
        if(seconds<10)
            seconds=timer2/1000;   
        else 
        seconds = timer2 / seconds_in_millies;

        if(seconds<10)
        seconds=timer2/100;   

        if(seconds>1&&seconds<2)                
        seconds=0;

          if(hours>=10&&minutes>=10&&seconds>=10)
           time.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
             else 
                 if (hours<10&&minutes>=10&&seconds>=10)
                 time.setText("0"+hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);            
                else 
                    if (hours<10&&minutes<10&&seconds>=10)
                    time.setText("0"+hours + ":0" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                else 
                    if (hours>=10&&minutes<10&&seconds<10)
                    time.setText("0"+hours + ":0" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
                else 
                    if(hours>=10&&minutes>=10&&seconds<10)
                         time.setText(hours + ":" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
                else 
                        if (hours>=10&&minutes<10&&seconds<10)
                         time.setText(hours + ":0" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
                        else 
                            if(hours>=10&&minutes<10&&seconds>=10)
                             time.setText(hours + ":0" + minutes+":" + seconds);
                            else if(hours<10&&minutes>=10 && seconds<10)
                                 time.setText("0"+hours + ":" + minutes +":0"+ seconds);


     }

     public void onFinish() 
     {  editor.clear();            
        this.start();
     }

  }.start();

     xtime=System.currentTimeMillis(); 
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = prefs.edit();
     editor2.putLong("time",xtime);         
     editor2.commit();
```

}

The SharedPreferences helps me restore the CountDownTimer from the point that the Activity ended using my algorithm. The problem is, even if I call the this.start() in my OnFinish() I have this NullPointerException Error on the line with this.start. I would appreciate some help. Thank you!
P.S: I also have a problem when the timer goes below 10 seconds, after that the following numbers appear but with a bonus digit. (95,85,75...15). If in my:

```
  if(seconds<10)
        seconds=timer2/1000;   
    else 
    seconds = timer2 / seconds_in_millies;
```

I would change the seconds=timer2/1000 with timer2/10000 it doesn't show the numbers at all and stops at 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this..

in your oncreate

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

 Date date = (Date)settings.getString("date",0);
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        Date d=c.getTime();
long diffInMs = d.getTime() - date.getTime();
long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMis);
if (diffInSec>86400)
{
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME",0);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = myPrefs.edit();
ed.putString("Date", String.valueOf(d));
ed.commit();
  //allow your activity to open
}
 else
{
 counter= new MyCount(diffInSec*1000,1000);
 counter.start();
 }
```

MyCount class

```
 public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
 public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
    Intent k=new Intent(Myactivity.this,Myactivity.class);
                 startActivity(k);
}
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    s1=millisUntilFinished;
     <---- display s1/1000 to show number of seconds left

}
}
```

}

hope this works..

Answer (score 2):

this gives you an endless countdown timer.. of 30 seconds.. you can count how many times new timer has been created to get total time elapsed.. like this

```
MyCount counter;
counter=new MyCount(30000,1000);
  counter.start();
```

MyCount class

```
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        counter= new MyCount(30000,1000);
     counter.start();
     n=n+1;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        s1=millisUntilFinished;
        r1=(30000-s1)/1000;


    }
    }



   }
```

to get total time elapsed...

```
int time=(n*30)+r1;<--- total time elapsed..
```

to pause timer use

```
counter.cancel();
```

to resume use

```
counter= new MyCount(s1,1000);
     counter.start();
```

Comment: I believe your code is good, I need to know how to implement it (I'm not quite advanced in Android developing). So, I need to copy this My Count class in my code and then? Also, I don't need to know the total time elapsed, so I will delete that part.

Comment: in your activity.. after oncreate paste this MyCount class..then in oncreate method of activity.. put this code..MyCount counter;
counter=new MyCount(30000,1000);;
  counter.start();

Comment: What should I do about my SharedPreferences, they need to be deleted in order to restart the timer.

Comment: err... i dint see anything about shared prefrence from your code.. jus suggested you to implement continuous countdowntimer like this..

Comment: I need the entire Activity to restart, with the CountDownTimer, only the second time with all SharedPreferences cleared (editor.clear()). But somehow if I restart the activity, my CountDownTimer won't restart.